# NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'productss' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]

Tags: java, spring, netbeans

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property
'productss' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property
'productss' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the
return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

After Url git put /Jenuaz

I have project on git: ShopJavaProject, and my git id: jenuaz.

Comment: You need to provide your code that produces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using this model attribure in OrderesController:

```
@ModelAttribute("orderes")
    public Orderes getFrom (){
        return new Orderes();
    }
```

And you have to use it on jps page form instead of `orderess`. Also the Product field is called `product` not `productss` and the list of Product is called `products`:

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" action="/admin/" method="POST" modelAttribute="orderes">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="orderes" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <form:select class="form-control" path="product" id="products" items="${products}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
            </div>
```